# iOS 13, CloudKit and CoreData Sync with custom zones for sharing

Tags: core-data, synchronization, cloudkit, zone

During WWDC 2019 Apple introduced `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` which allows for syncing of CoreData with CloudKit. It is a great addition. In iOS 13 in notes app also user is allowed to to share the entire note "FOLDER" with another user. Given that Apple uses CloudKit for Notes app, I wanted to create something similar to understand how it better works.

Apple creates `com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone` zone and basically syncs all data there into that zone if all setup conditions are met. However there is no guideline when user would like to share data. According to a former WWDC talk, sharing would be possible mainly via creating a CUSTOM ZONE. However the new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` provides no possible way to change the zone for each entity in the CoreData.

I was very happy to have found these

```c
open func record(for managedObjectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> CKRecord?

open func records(for managedObjectIDs: [NSManagedObjectID]) -> [NSManagedObjectID : CKRecord]

open func recordID(for managedObjectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> CKRecordID?

open func recordIDs(for managedObjectIDs: [NSManagedObjectID]) -> [NSManagedObjectID : CKRecordID]
```

as they gave this impression that the container calls this methods to retrieve the CKRecord and hence a point to modify informations such as zone etc. but after the setup I realized when I add a new entity to my CoreData, these functions even though when overrides are not called.

My question in short is: how to take controll of how `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` manages which record belongs to which zone other than `com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone`

Comment: Also would be nice to have some info on how sharing works with new cloud kit container

Comment: iOS 14 is bringing some of this to live https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontaineroptions/3580372-databasescope

Comment: You have a similar question here with more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585361/3641812

Comment: `com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone` is already a custom zone, so you can make any changes to this zone as you want.