# Mirroring Shared data CoreData + CloudKit

Tags: swift, core-data, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I've set up Core Data mirroring using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer and it works well. I also managed how to create share for records. But how I can get shared record synced with the non-owner's Core Data?

Example:
User A (owner) shared record with user B, how that record (with 1-to-many relationship) can be synchronised with user B Core Data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Share Core Data between users with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768719/share-core-data-between-users-with-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer)

Comment: No, Ben, there is no answer in that thread. The question is similar but no answer at all.